# Can you embed normal SSL content on an EV SSL page?

Tags: ssl, browser

I have a domain secured with an EV SSL certificate, say https://example.net. Now that page will include content from a static source https://examplecdn.com/ secured with a normal (not EV but domain verified) certificate.

Is this possible or will it invalidate the EV certificate (green address bar) on example.net?

-- ooxi

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can switch to any SSL certificate without changing content of your website or Page. Simply You have to change only certificate not content.

Comment: That does not at all answer the question. The question was about whether or not it is possible to include content from different certificate degrees while retaining the highest degree.

Comment: there will be no issue with your example.net domain if you user domain validated certificate website within EV certificate content.